# Creating a symlink inside profile.d doesn't work. Workaround?

Tags: profile, etc

I have created a special folder (`/usr/manual`) for everything I install manually. This way when I reinstall the OS or change my laptop all I have to do is move `/home` and `/usr/manual/` and reinstall the package list.

So because of my decision to never manually add files anywhere except `/home` and `/usr/manual` I'm looking for a way to put all the custom environment variables inside `/usr/manual/`.

I have created a symlink inside `profile.d`: `/etc/profile.d/usrprofile` pointing to `/usr/manual/profile.d`. But the files in `/usr/manual/profile.d` never get executed: it seems that the parser can't handle symlinks.

Is there an easy way to solve my problem?

Comment: Why `/usr/manual`? That's what `/usr/local` is for.

Comment: @Gilles Because `/usr/local/` has stuff in it that I didn't put there. It was installed by `apt` or by different installer scripts and the entire purpose of my setup is separating files I install manually from files installed by installers.

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/profile` script normally sources files in `/etc/profile.d` that are ending with `.sh` and does not take care of subfolders. 
So you would have to link every single `.sh` file from your `/usr/manual/profile.d` directory, or you write a wrapper that is inside `/etc/profile.d` that takes care of your own `.sh` files in `/usr/manual/profile.d`. While thinking about it, the latter one might be the more elegant.

Comment: A wrapper script is a good idea! But (at the risk of coming off criminally punctilious) is it much better than just having all the `.sh` scripts I have right now?
Here's what I have in mind: if I forget to move my scripts when I move to a new machine, I might have to create them from scratch. If they are in `/usr/manual/` and I forget to move the symlink, that's no big deal, I just make a new one. If I have the wrapper script in `/etc/profile.d/` and I forget to move it, I have to write the wrapper script again.

Comment: @0x60 Make a symbolic link to the wrapper script.